# Auto Build MVC app on after code behind change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, build

In old sweet Web Forms times, when we make change on code behind, once we hit the application, it was compiling on the fly and running new changed code.

For Web Apps and MVC, when I add a new controller or change something on business logic, I have to always build app on VS 2015 manually and go back to browser and test again. But many times I keep forgetting building till I see yellow error screen.

Is there any way to kick build if there is code change and **if I hit the website first time** like Web Forms? I **would not prefer to build on save** since I am a ctrl + S freak, and keep pressing that combo on every other second.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge Dynamic Compilation is not available in an MVC application because it won't be a "Web Site" project, it will be a "Web Application" project. Only Web Site projects can do dynamic compilation, since with MVC you're routing to actions in the controller my guess is it has to be compiled in advance - unlike ASP.NET where you're routing to a physical file.